# Is it possible to change the transition-delay when hover out?

Tags: css

Quite straight forward question. I wonder if and how you can change the delay on a hover when its on its "out"-state. The code below gives the element a transition of .25s, but lets say i want it to be .40s when mouse-out, or what you like to call it. How?

Example code for demonstration purpose:

HTML

```
<a href="#">Text></a>
```

CSS

```
a:hover {
  transition: all .5s linear;
  transition-delay: .25s;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve a different transition-delay when hovering out, you need to set the transition properties on the element's normal state. The `:hover` pseudo-class will only control the hover-in transition. E.g.:

```
a {
 transition: all .4s linear; 
}

a:hover {
  transition: all .5s linear;
  transition-delay: .25s;
  opacity: .5;
}
```